# convolution of .mat file and 1D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as spio

x=np.zeros((22113,1),float)

x= spio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\'
                'FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\kk.mat')

print(x)

x = np.reshape(len(x),1);

h = np.array([0.9,0.3,0.1],float)

print(h)

h = h.reshape(len(h),1);

dd = np.convolve(h,x)
```

and the error I encounter is "**ValueError: object too deep for desired array**"
kindly help me in this reguard.

Comment: Which line do you recieve the error on?

Comment: After the load what is `x`?  Show the print.  You may have to index into it get the actual array.

Comment: That initial `x=np.zeros...` line does nothing for you.  You don't define the shape or type of variables before hand.  `x` is set by the `loadmat` command.

Comment: @Eric I got this error in the following line dd = np.convolve(h,x)

Comment: @hpaulj x is an audio file in .mat format and it contains float values

Comment: What is its `shape` and `dtype`?

Answer (score 1):

```
{'__globals__': [], '__version__': '1.0', 'ans': array([[ 0.13580322,
 0.13580322], [ 0.13638306, 0.13638306], [ 0.13345337, 0.13345337], 
 ..., [ 0.13638306, 0.13638306], [ 0.13345337, 0.13345337], ..., [   
 0.13638306, 0.13638306], [ 0.13345337, 0.13345337], ..., [-0.09136963,    
-0.09136963], [-0.12442017, -0.12442017], [-0.15542603, -0.15542603]])}
```

See {}?  That means `x` from the `loadmat` is a dictionary.

`x['ans']` will be an array

```
array([[ 0.13580322,
     0.13580322], [ 0.13638306, 0.13638306], [ 0.13345337, 0.13345337],...]])
```

which, if I count the [] right is a (n,2) array of floats.

The following line does not make sense:

```
x = np.reshape(len(x),1);
```

I suspect you mean `x = x.reshape(...)` as you do with `h`.  But that would give an error with the dictionary `x`.

When you say `the shape of x is (9,) and its dtype is uint16` - where in your code you verifying that?

Answer (score 0):

`x = np.reshape(len(x),1);` doesn't do anything useful. That completely discards the data in x, and creates an array of shape `(1,)`, with the only element being `len(x)`.

In your code, you reshape `h` to `(3, 1)`, which is a 2D array, not a 1D array, which is why `convolve` complains.

Remove both of your `reshape`s, and instead just pass `squeeze=True` to `scipy.io.loadmat` - this is needed because matlab does not have the concept as 1d arrays, and squeeze tells scipy to try and flatten `(N, 1)` and `(1, N)` arrays to `(N,)` arrays

Comment: 'import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio

x=np.zeros((22113,1),float)

x= sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\kk.mat')

print(x)

squeeze=True

h = np.array([0.9,0.3,0.1],float)

dd = np.convolve(h,x)'    _when i did as you directed then i got this error_ **return multiarray.correlate(a, v[::-1], mode)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'dict'**

Comment: `import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio

x=np.zeros((22113,1),float)

x= sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\kk.mat')

print(x)

squeeze=True

h = np.array([0.9,0.3,0.1],float)

dd = np.convolve(h,x)`  when i did as you directed then i got this error return multiarray.correlate(a, v[::-1], mode) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'dict' in the line **dd = np.convolve(h,x)**

Comment: Your `x` is not the array itself.  It is a dictionary that contains one or more arrays.  You need to read the `loadmat` documentation, and look at `x`.  Don't just throw it into your calculations without first understanding what it is.

Comment: @hpaulj x is an audio .wav file in .mat format and it contains float values

Comment: @hpaulj **the load shows** `{'__globals__': [], '__version__': '1.0', 'ans': array([[ 0.13580322,  0.13580322],
       [ 0.13638306,  0.13638306],
       [ 0.13345337,  0.13345337],
       ...,
       [ 0.13638306,  0.13638306],
       [ 0.13345337,  0.13345337],
       ...,
       [ 0.13638306,  0.13638306],
       [ 0.13345337,  0.13345337],
       ...,
       [-0.09136963, -0.09136963],
       [-0.12442017, -0.12442017],
       [-0.15542603, -0.15542603]])}`

Comment: @hpaulj the shape of x is (9,) and its dtype is uint16